# I have one Query related to background and foreground tableview reload data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, background-foreground

hello every one good noon,
I have one Query related to background and foreground.

In my application in table view cell I display the image from URL with the help of `AFNetworking` .Ok

Now my Main query is When I scroll up images is displayed in cell and after 20 to 25 images is display in table then I press home button and app goes to background and after some second(10 to 20 sec) when I click on app icon and app comes to foreground and I scroll down then some images is reload .

So it's right or Wrong
NOTE:- I am not talking about force QUIT (Just foreground to background and again foreground).

Comment: image load on cell when will be visible on screen

Comment: Sounds like normal behavior to me. When your app is in the background it should relinquish as many resources it can to bring down its memory footprint. By doing this it will reduce the probability that the system purge the whole app when in need of memory.

Comment: Are you by chance saving the images in cache or loading the url directly onto the cell?